# Click on button not working

Tags: java, android, robotium

I am new to robotium and now I am automating the app.

App starts with a splash screen and then the menu screen after 15 seconds of loading 1ndicator, in the menu screen there is a button named *Application*. When I proceed with click on that button it returns an error.

NOTE: When I used search text it returns that button with name is present

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

public void testCanOpenSettings() throws Exception {

     String appName = solo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().getSimpleName();
     System.out.println(appName);
     String appName1 = solo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().getSimpleName();
     System.out.println(appName1); 
     solo.assertCurrentActivity("Home screen", appName1); 
     solo.waitForActivity(appName1, 10000);
     solo.clickonbutton("Application");
}

@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    try {
        solo.finalize();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    getActivity().finish();
    super.tearDown();
}
```

Stack trace:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No Button with text Application is found!
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getView(ViewFetcher.java:350)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.getButton(Solo.java:1233)
at com.impiger.fff.controller.Test.testCanOpenSettings(Test.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:205)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:195)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:175)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:444)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the name of the button is Application like this android:text="Application"?

Comment: Based on your code "solo.clickonbutton("Application");", are all small letters, it must be camel case like "solo.clickOnButton("Application");"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is a button? Try clickOnText() instead.